# MonoDevelop compiling options

Tags: macos, settings, compilation, monodevelop

I'm developing applications in MonoDevelop for the first time today, and I just need to know how to compile my projects for mac, NOT windows.

When I click "Compile" after right clicking on my project, I always get an exe file. (Which, when tested, DOES work as programmed) That's all fine, and good, but being a mac user, I could really use a way to compile to Mac .app files.

Answer (score 6):

Creating `.exe` files is the whole point. See the [Mono manual](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX):

> At this point, you must use Mono from the command line, the usual set of commands that are available on other ports of Mono are available.
>
> To build applications you can use "gmcs", to run then you can use mono.
>
> From a Terminal shell, you can try it out:
>
> `$ vi hello.cs` 
> `$ gcs hello.cs`
> `$ mono hello.exe`
> `Hello, World`
> `$`

and

> Running applications on MacOS X is very similar to linux systems, from the terminal:
>
> `mono myprogram.exe`

Comment: With that info, it shouldn't be too terribly difficult to package that into a .app using XCode.

Answer (score 2):

To make an app bundle from a GTK# or System.Windows.Forms app, follow these instructions: http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2010/01/24/creating_mac_app_bundle_for_gtk_app

If you have a MonoMac project, MD will create the app bundle automatically.

Comment: Turns out I can't even compile the project to work for windows. I AM using GTK#, and my GTK# exe files are not even running in windows, whereas my console programs DID. Furthermore, I don't even know if I'm compiling properly. Could you please explain to me how to properly compile in MonoDevelop? Thanks! :) (And that includes making sure I know where the files are being saved to)

Comment: Hard to do that without more information, or knowing how much you need explained.